# Firebase push ID, retrieving the ID in a different JS file

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, frontend

My question is about the unique ID generated when using push to append new entry in database.
I am using push and ref.key to push new entry and get the push ID, but if I am on a different page with different Javascript file how can I get the ID again?

```
JohnSmith86: {
              -abcdefjhigklmno { //the unique pudh ID
                                 Name: John Smith
               }
             }
```

Given that I am on a different page and different JS file I can retrieve JohnSmith86 key from the data base, but how I can get the ID? apparently the key() would work when we push the entry for the first time.
what I want to do is just logging JohnSmith86.pushID.Name

Comment: If you're transitioning to a different page and want to keep the state, you will have to pass that state (in your case the key) from the first page to the second. Typically you'd do that as a parameter in the URL, e.g. `https//myapp.firebaseappcom/page2.html?key=-abcdefjhigklmno`